# Excel VBA Date Picker issue

Tags: vba, excel, date, datepicker

I hope you can help. I have a date picker that pops up on column H as I wanted to standardize how dates were entered on the the Excel sheet. The issue I am facing is that if I or any of my team based in Dublin click on a cell in column H from Cell H10 down then the date picker pops up and it records the date as i want 05/11/2017 or "mm/dd/yyyy"

Now if my team mates in other countries like Denmark or Finland click on a cell below H10 the date format is returned .5.11.17 it is not returning the 05/11/2017 format

In screen shot 1 you can see a visual representation of my issue.

The code for the pop up calendar is in two modules as you can see in Screen Shot 2

My Code is below Can any one solve this issue?

**As always any and all help is greatly appreciated**

I leveraged this date picker from code online so I don't fully understand it.

But my code is below

Code from 2nd Module of Class Module in Screen Shot 2 is here

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
     'check cells for desired format to trigger the calendarfrm.show routine
     'otherwise exit the sub
    Dim DateFormats, DF
    DateFormats = Array("m/d/yy;@", "mm/dd/yyyy")
    For Each DF In DateFormats
        If DF = Target.NumberFormat Then
            If CalendarFrm.HelpLabel.Caption <> "" Then
                CalendarFrm.Height = 191 + CalendarFrm.HelpLabel.Height
            Else: CalendarFrm.Height = 191
                CalendarFrm.Show
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And the code from the Calendar Form is here

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin {C62A69F0-16DC-11CE-9E98-00AA00574A4F} CalendarFrm 
   Caption         =   "Calendar Control"
   ClientHeight    =   3690
   ClientLeft      =   45
   ClientTop       =   360
   ClientWidth     =   3960
   OleObjectBlob   =   "CalendarFrm.frx":0000
   StartUpPosition =   1  'CenterOwner
End
Attribute VB_Name = "CalendarFrm"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False



Option Explicit
    Dim ThisDay As Date
    Dim ThisYear, ThisMth As Date
    Dim CreateCal As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'starts the form on todays date
    ThisDay = Date
    ThisMth = Format(ThisDay, "mm")
    ThisYear = Format(ThisDay, "yyyy")
    For i = 1 To 12
        CB_Mth.AddItem Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + i, 0), "mmmm")
    Next
    CB_Mth.ListIndex = Format(Date, "mm") - Format(Date, "mm")
    For i = -20 To 50
        If i = 1 Then CB_Yr.AddItem Format((ThisDay), "yyyy") Else CB_Yr.AddItem _
            Format((DateAdd("yyyy", (i - 1), ThisDay)), "yyyy")
    Next
    CB_Yr.ListIndex = 21
    'Builds the calendar with todays date
    CalendarFrm.Width = CalendarFrm.Width
    CreateCal = True
    Call Build_Calendar
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
Private Sub CB_Mth_Change()
    'rebuilds the calendar when the month is changed by the user
    Build_Calendar
End Sub
Private Sub CB_Yr_Change()
    'rebuilds the calendar when the year is changed by the user
    Build_Calendar
End Sub
Private Sub Build_Calendar()
    'the routine that actually builds the calendar each time
    If CreateCal = True Then
    CalendarFrm.Caption = " " & CB_Mth.Value & " " & CB_Yr.Value
    'sets the focus for the todays date button
    CommandButton1.SetFocus
    For i = 1 To 42
        If i < Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value)) Then
            Controls("D" & (i)).Caption = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
                ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "d")
            Controls("D" & (i)).ControlTipText = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
                ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy")
        ElseIf i >= Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value)) Then
            Controls("D" & (i)).Caption = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) _
                & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "d")
            Controls("D" & (i)).ControlTipText = Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
                ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy")
        End If
        If Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
        ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "mmmm") = ((CB_Mth.Value)) Then
            If Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor <> &H80000016 Then Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor = &H80000018  '&H80000010
            Controls("D" & (i)).Font.Bold = True
        If Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), _
            ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy") = Format(ThisDay, "m/d/yy") Then Controls("D" & (i)).SetFocus
        Else
            If Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor <> &H80000016 Then Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor = &H8000000F
            Controls("D" & (i)).Font.Bold = False
        End If
    Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub D1_Click()
    'this sub and the ones following represent the buttons for days on the form
    'retrieves the current value of the individual controltiptext and
    'places it in the active cell
    ActiveCell.Value = D1.ControlTipText
    Unload Me
    'after unload you can call a different userform to continue data entry
    'uncomment this line and add a userform named UserForm2
    'Userform2.Show

End Sub
Private Sub D2_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D2.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D3_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D3.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D4_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D4.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D5_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D5.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D6_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D6.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D7_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D7.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D8_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D8.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D9_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D9.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D10_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D10.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D11_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D11.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D12_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D12.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D13_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D13.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D14_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D14.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D15_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D15.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D16_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D16.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D17_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D17.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D18_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D18.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D19_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D19.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D20_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D20.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D21_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D21.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D22_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D22.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D23_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D23.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D24_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D24.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D25_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D25.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D26_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D26.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D27_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D27.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D28_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D28.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D29_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D29.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D30_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D30.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D31_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D31.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D32_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D32.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D33_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D33.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D34_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D34.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D35_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D35.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D36_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D36.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D37_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D37.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D38_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D38.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D39_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D39.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D40_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D40.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D41_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D41.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub D42_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = D42.ControlTipText
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Screen Shot 1
[image]

Screen Shot 2 [image]

Comment: While writing date back onto the sheet try Format(CalendarControl.Value, "mm/dd/yyyy"). Replace Calendarcontrol with name of your actual calendar control.

Comment: Hi Sktneer Thank you for taking the time to respond. I dont think changing the calendar control will work the Calendar Control has the format as "m/d/yy" which would still return 5/12/17 I am getting a date format with 05.12.17 back from team mates in other countries. Again thank you for the effort I am very grateful

Comment: The issue here is that you are pushing a date -formatted as text- into the cell, where the date format of your calendar form does not match the windows date settings of your user. Excel will then try to convert the formatted text to a true date and in some situations fail, like 31/12/2017 or 12/31/2017. See: http://oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Default.htm

Comment: The control will return the date in correct format for you as your regional settings follow the US format. Using the Format function, you can force the code to retain the US format for the users where you get date in wrong format. Did you try that?

Comment: At Sktneer No I have not tried that how would i do that though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the activecell in every private sub for click events.

For example:

```
Private Sub D6_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = cDate(D35.ControlTipText)
    activecell.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Kelaref Thank you for taking the time to respond unfortunately your attempt to help as not worked. My Finish team mate has just shown me that the date format returns with 5.12.17 and not 05/12/17. Is there another method?

Comment: Edited to add cDate

Comment: Kelaref Thank you so much for taking the time to solve this issued for me. The only country it wont work for is Finland  but for all others it seems to be working. So I thought it only fair to accept your answer. Again thank you for the help.