# Date Picker issue - Monday - first weekday

Tags: excel, vba, colors, commandbutton

In the USA, the first day of the week is *Sunday*, but in many European countries the first day is considered *Monday* (see the attached captures). I was able to make it show the calendar accordingly, but there is an issue regarding the colors.

Sunday - first day of the week

[image]

Monday - first day of the week

[image]

The days of the month changed accordingly, but the colors of each CommandButton remain the same (see the *light-yellow* colored area).
The portion of code which controls these colors is found in

```
Sub Build_Calendar()

If Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value)), vbMonday), _
        ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "mmmm") = ((CB_Mth.Value)) Then
            If Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor <> &H80000016 Then Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor = &H80000018  '&H80000010
            Controls("D" & (i)).Font.Bold = True
        If Format(DateAdd("d", (i - Weekday((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value)), vbMonday), _
            ((CB_Mth.Value) & "/1/" & (CB_Yr.Value))), "m/d/yy") = Format(ThisDay, "m/d/yy") Then Controls("D" & (i)).SetFocus
        Else
            If Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor <> &H80000016 Then Controls("D" & (i)).BackColor = &H8000000F
            Controls("D" & (i)).Font.Bold = False
        End If
```

Does it know anyone in which way should I modify this code in order to have proper colors of the CommandButtons?

Thank you,

Dan

Comment: Seeing only a small slice of an obvious larger code, it is difficult to understand the global logic. We can only guess and this is not something good for a question. You do not say anything about the involved controls. Anyhow, it if is a matter of guessing, I would suggest to adapt the code in a way to calculate `Weekday` (for `vbMonday`) **for the day on the control** and change its `BackColor` according to the result. (**6 and 7** being darker). You should see such a line in the existing code, the single difference being `vbSunday` (1, 7) against `vbMonday`. You should modify it accordingly.

Comment: I don't think the code needs changing, just swap the default backcolor on the controls D1 <> D6, D8 <> D13 etc

Comment: @FaneDuru: thank you so much for your suggestions! I have already done the first part (used *vbMonday*), but I have difficulties regarding the second part. The full code is listed in **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932490/excel-vba-date-picker-issue** and the fragment of code I cited (minus *vbMonday* use) is present  in *Private Sub Build_Calendar()*.

Comment: @CDP1802: I have made a mistake not telling you about the full code for this Date Picker. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932490/excel-vba-date-picker-issue. As you can see, the code for *Private Sub D1_Click()* up to *D42* is absolutely the same, so the code responsible for different colors should be elsewhere.

Comment: @DanEnache What is the BackColor property for D1 and D6 ?

Comment: @CDP1802: D1.BackColor=&H80000016& and D1.BackColor=&H8000000F&. Now I understand what you meant. I have modified the BackColor for D1, D8, D15, D22, D29 and D36 from &H8000000F& to &H80000016& and the reverse modification for D6, D13, D20, D27, D34 and D41. Atferwards, I have modified a little the code, switching &H80000018 and &H8000000F. Thank you so much, CDP1802! Your suggestion solved my problem!

Comment: @CDP1802: sorry, the code needs no update. So I did exactly what you suggested.

Comment: @danenache thanks, I couldn't see why a code change was required. All that complicated code is just selecting cells in the display month.

Comment: Since first and seventh (control) columns are static (not changed), you should color them in the form and they will keep that color for ever... :) Or in code using their name (D1, D8, D15, D22, D29  and D36).